# How to enter a positive integer value and then return it?

Tags: python

I'm really stuck with a question asking me to enter a positive integer value and then return that positive integer value:

[image]

I've tried entering this code:

```
def get_positive_integer(integer):
    get_positive_integer = int(integer)
    return get_positive_integer

integer = input("Please enter a positive integer value: ")
the_integer = get_positive_integer(integer)
print(the_integer)
```

But I have no idea how to get the answer which is required of me.

How do I go about solving this? I'm confused as the function `get_positive_integer` does not take any parameters. How am I meant to return the number the user inputs if it does not take any parameters?

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Instead, copy the text, [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code) and [blockquotes](/editing-help#simple-blockquotes).

Comment: Hint: *"the `get_positive_integer()` function takes no parameters"*

Comment: @wjandrea this is what I'm confused about. If it takes no parameters, how can it return a number?

Comment: Oh, why didn't you say so? I thought you just missed that part. Please [edit] the question to clarify, and I can remove my downvote.

Comment: Another hint: `get_positive_integer()` "prompts the user to enter a positive integer value and then returns this value."

Comment: What do you mean *"If it takes no parameters, how can it return a number?"*? The two are not related. A function can take any number of arguments (including 0), and return any number of values regardless. Just move the `input(...)` line inside the function itself...

Comment: Looks like you know how to code but don't know where to put it.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“I have no idea” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.
You *have* written some code, but did so without first understanding the assignment requirements.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). This suggests a collection of needs that are too broad for Stack Overflow.  However, I suggest doing some incremental programming: pick *one* feature of the assignment to start, such as writing a function to read an integer.  Program and test that.  *Only* when that works, add a line or two that will return that integer to the calling program.  Test that addition.  Extend until solved ... or until you're stuck on a *specific* point -- then post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it wants something like this:

```
def get_positive_integer():
    return int(input("Please enter a positive integer value: "))
```

There aren't any parameters because you can assume `input` is actually going to give you an `int`.

Answer (score 2):

The requirements say "the `get_positive_integer()` function takes no parameters", but you've given it a parameter. You're supposed to put the `input()` inside the function:

```
def get_positive_integer():
    positive_integer = int(input("Please enter a positive integer value: "))
    return positive_integer


the_integer = get_positive_integer()
print(the_integer, type(the_integer))
```

Example run:

```
Please enter a positive integer value: 15
15 <class 'int'>
```

By the way, I removed the `get_` from the inner variable name since it was confusing.